# Battery charger IC max. discharge current

Tags: batteries, integrated-circuit, battery-charging, bms

I want to incorporate a battery charger IC to my design which has around 8 A maximum battery discharge current.

I want the charger IC to boost my 5 V USB input to charge 2S Li-ion batteries (8.4 V) with around 1-1.5 A charge current.

I found the [LTC4020](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/4020fd.pdf) and [LT1512](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/1512fc.pdf) which seem suitable for my application, but I couldn't find any information about the maximum discharge current (maybe there is no limit on the IC side?).

I was wondering if these ICs use some kind of external power path that allows high current usage compared to similar ICs with internal MOSFETs?

The 8 A discharge current will only be used while the charger is disconnected. Consumption during the charging state will be 50-100 mA maximum.

Comment: You don't appear to have asked a question. Will the discharge current mess with detecting the end of the CV charge? Yes it will. Can we recommend a better charger IC? No, that's against site policy. Note that at the end of the CV phase, you have enough charger current capaibility to source your load current as well. If that's routed directly to the load, the battery will not be discharging, and standard end of charge current detect will work properly. Was your question how to do that?

Comment: @Neil_UK Not exactly. I am looking to use full discharge current capabilities of the battery with these IC's. Some charger ICs mention maximum discharge current so i was wondering if these use some sort of external power route to avoid that problem. My circuit detects charge input and switches to charge mode so I will never need to supply high current load while it's plugged in but only in disconnected mode.